# How to implement accessibility service to perform screen lock with GLOBAL_ACTION_LOCK_SCREEN? I prefer Kotlin code please

Tags: android, kotlin, service

I need lock screen via accessibility service, I can d it with DEVICE ADMIN, but can't find any manual to implement it with AS.

I tried to follow official documentation, but it's not beginner friendly at all. I also tried with many other manuals, but no success. Please help.

P.S. this is my first ever question on Stackoverflow.